# Connecting nodes to existing network lines using QGIS

Tags: qgis, line, network, connection, nodes

I have road network (polyline layer) and point layer:

- I am trying to connect nodes to the existing network lines. I able to connect nodes with lines using `connect nodes to lines` in `Networks` in QGIS as shown in first image.

**The problem here is:** It creates seperate line to connect node to line as shown with green circle in the image. I am trying to connect node in the existing line instead of creating new line as shown in Image 2.

I have searched **existing answers** to:

- [Joining nodes to network lines ( and not other points) using GRASS](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/56685)
- [Connecting points with lines using QGIS](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/317461)
- [Connecting points with line using virtual layer in QGIS](http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/387937)

but the listed solutions are only for conventional point to line connections.

[image: ![![enter image description here]

Image 2:

[image]

Comment: Sorry, your question is not clear to me. I can't see the difference in your two screenshots. Can you explain more precisely what is the problem with Connect nodes to line? Somehow, there must be created a new line - without it, you won't have any connection?

Comment: @Babel.The Connect nodes to line process should split the existing network lines and connect the nodes in between instead of creating new line to create the nearest node. Is that clear?